# Negative energy solutions not a problem for Klein-Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, antimatter, klein-gordon-equation

I already posed this question [Negative energy solutions in Klein-Gordon and Dirac equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/652283/77255) but I am not satisfied with the answers.
Trying to be very sharp:

- does Klein-Gordon equation have negative energy solutions like Dirac one or are they (the solutions) somehow different?
- if they are the same, why the problem of negative energy is always referred to Dirac equation and not to KG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the Klein-Gordon and Dirac equations, if interpreted as RQM equations, have negative solutions.

It is not that we are saying that Klein-Gordon gets a free pass. It is that nobody cared about the Klein-Gordon equation until relatively recently, because there was no known fundamental use of the Klein-Gordon equation until Higgs.

Note that Schrödinger derived the Klein-Gordon equation before specialising to his non-relativistic equation. He knew about the negative solutions, but it was most convincing that it was ``wrong" that the relativistic corrections of the Klein-Gordon equation is in the opposite direction to that of the Dirac equation, the latter of which agreed with the experimental data of even back then. Schrödinger thus abandoned the relativistic approach and published the non-relativistic equation.

So, no, Klein-Gordon equation's negative solutions are bad too.

However, Dirac equation had it slightly better. Not only does it get spin-half, for the short few years, they could pretend that the negative solutions are filled. This possibility comes from fermion statistics, and the combination of the spin-half nature, i.e. it is the correct equation for electrons, and the possibility that spin-half opens up fermion statistics to try and fix this negative solutions problem, that warrants more words to be spent upon it.

That is, Dirac equation's negative energy solutions are much less toxic than Klein-Gordon, because Klein-Gordon has to obey boson statistics, and so almost all the bosons in Klein-Gordon would drop to infinitely negative energies if that was a possibility.

In the end, though, the negative solutions in Dirac equation *cannot* be ignored by saying that those states are all filled up. This is because, the moment you introduce interactions, the infinite sea of electrons would also interact, and the problem becomes intractable.

Therefore, for *both* Klein-Gordon and Dirac equations, *the only acceptable view of them, is that they are quantum field equations.* Only by the machinery of QFT, can the negative energy solutions be all recast as positive energies, and then there is no more problem. i.e. RQM is not a sensible theory at all, only QFT is possible.

Comment: You can also interpret these equations as *classical* field equations, where no solutions have negative energy.  The corresponding solutions are then called "negative frequency solutions", but for a wave of the form sin(kx-wt), changing the sign of w doesn't change the energy, it flips the direction of wave propagation.   QM interprets such "negative frequency" waves as having negative energy using analysis from non-relativistic QM and assuming that the same analysis also applies to relativistic QM.  But a relativistic classical analysis has no trouble with these solutions at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Klein-Gordon equation has -- if the field fullfilling the equation is assumed to be complex -- positive and negative energy solutions.

First of all, it is not always deferred to the Dirac-equation, for instance the book: "QFT for the gifted amateur" already treats  negative energy solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation.
Actually, one of the reasons Schroedinger did not base his work for an electron-wave equation on the Klein-Gordon equation was the fact that it had "strange solutions" also making the probability current indefinite.

The negative energy solutions of the Dirac-equation are not equal to the negative energy solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation, but the difference between the  negative and positive energy solutions of Dirac-equation is more eye-catchy.

In general positive and negative energy solutions are related by an operation called "charge conjugation $C$". Applied on Klein-Gordon solutions it is just a complex conjugation:

$$C e^{-ipx} = (e^{-ipx})^\ast  = e^{ipx}$$

Charge conjugation of Dirac's single particle solutions also affects the part apart from the phase factor:

$$ C (u e^{-ipx}) = {\cal{}C}\bar{u}^T (e^{-ipx})^\ast = v e^{ipx}$$

Note the difference of notation of the charge conjugation operator. As a whole I call it $C$, whereas if it is only applied on $u$ or $v$ it is denoted with ${\cal{C}}$.

Note that the Klein-Gordon equation works very well too, but at the end of the 1920 -- the time of Schroedinger and Dirac -- the pions which follow a wave-equation which is Klein-Gordon were still not discovered.